# Angular named router-outlet from submodule remains empty

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 5.0.0.  I am trying to have a side menu and then when a menu option is clicked the appropriate contents appear in rest of the screen.

I have a ProposalsModule that holds all the components which may be retrieved from the side menu.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { SharedModule } from '../../common-components/shared.module';
import { ProposalsRoutingModule } from './proposals-routing.module';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { ProposalStatusComponent } from './proposal-status/proposal-status.component';
import { ProposalConfigComponent } from './proposal-config/proposal-config.component';
import { ProposalStdDeliveryComponent } from './proposal-std-delivery/proposal-std-delivery.component';
import { ProposalTemplateComponent } from './proposal-template/proposal-template.component';
import { ProposalItemMnfgTimeComponent } from './proposal-item-mnfg-time/proposal-item-mnfg-time.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    ProposalsRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProposalConfigComponent,
    ProposalStatusComponent,
    ProposalStdDeliveryComponent,
    ProposalTemplateComponent,
    ProposalItemMnfgTimeComponent
  ]
})
export class ProposalsModule { }
```

Here is the ProposalsRoutingModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ProposalConfigComponent } from './proposal-config/proposal-config.component';
import { ProposalStatusComponent } from './proposal-status/proposal-status.component';
import { ProposalStdDeliveryComponent } from './proposal-std-delivery/proposal-std-delivery.component';
import { ProposalItemMnfgTimeComponent } from './proposal-item-mnfg-time/proposal-item-mnfg-time.component';
import { ProposalTemplateComponent } from './proposal-template/proposal-template.component';

const proposalRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'config', component: ProposalConfigComponent },
    { path: 'status', component: ProposalStatusComponent, outlet: 'proposalconfig' },
    { path: 'stddelivery', component: ProposalStdDeliveryComponent, outlet: 'proposalconfig' },
    { path: 'itemmnfgtime', component: ProposalItemMnfgTimeComponent, outlet: 'proposalconfig' },
    { path: 'template', component: ProposalTemplateComponent, outlet: 'proposalconfig' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forChild(proposalRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
      RouterModule
  ]
})
export class ProposalsRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the html for the page:

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Proposal Configuration</mat-card-subtitle>
        <mat-list>
            <mat-list-item>
                <button mat-button [routerLink]="['',{ outlets: { proposalconfig: ['status'] } }]" routerLinkActive="active">Statuses</button>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
                <button mat-button [routerLink]="['',{ outlets: { proposalconfig: ['stddelivery'] } }]" routerLinkActive="active">Standard Delivery</button>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
                <button mat-button [routerLink]="['',{ outlets: { proposalconfig: ['itemmnfgtime'] } }]" routerLinkActive="active">Item Manufacturing Time</button>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
                <button mat-button [routerLink]="['',{ outlets: { proposalconfig: ['template'] } }]" routerLinkActive="active">Templates</button>
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
    </mat-card>

    <router-outlet name="proposalconfig"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And here is my main routing module:

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent }   from './home/home.component';
import { ManufacturingMachineComponent }      from './administrative/utilities/manufacturing-machine/manufacturing-machine.component';
import { ProposalConfigComponent } from './sales/proposals/proposal-config/proposal-config.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'Home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'administrative/utilities/manufacturingmachine', component: ManufacturingMachineComponent },
  { path: 'administrative/utilities/units', loadChildren: 'app/administrative/utilities/units/units.module#UnitsModule' },
  { path: 'sales/proposals', loadChildren: 'app/sales/proposals/proposals.module#ProposalsModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'Home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true }) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

If I navigate to /sales/proposals/config, then my side menu shows up as expected, and I don't see any errors.  If I click any of the menu options, there are no errors and the url changes to what I believe is the correct url.  For example, `http://localhost:4200/sales/proposals/config(proposalconfig:status)`.  The problem is that the components are not actually showing up in the named outlet.

I suspect that I am missing an import somewhere or something like that, but I can't figure out what it is.  Anyone see anything missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what the problem was with the above approach, but I ended up making all of the above components part of a ProposalConfig module.  I then put an [unnamed] `<router-outlet></router-outlet` in the html for the ProposalConfig component.  I then added a ProposalConfigRouting Module which contained:

```
const proposalConfigRoutes: Routes = [
    {   
        path: 'sales/proposals/config',
        component: ProposalConfigComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'status', component: ProposalStatusComponent },
            { path: 'stddelivery', component: ProposalStdDeliveryComponent },
            { path: 'itemmnfgtime', component: ProposalItemMnfgTimeComponent },
            { path: 'template', component: ProposalTemplateComponent }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forChild(proposalConfigRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
      RouterModule
  ]
})
export class ProposalConfigRoutingModule { }
```

The html for the ProposalConfig component (the side menu) then became:

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Proposal Configuration</mat-card-subtitle>
        <mat-list>
            <mat-list-item>
                <button mat-button routerLink="status" routerLinkActive="active">Statuses</button>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
                <button mat-button routerLink="stddelivery" routerLinkActive="active">Standard Delivery</button>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
                <button mat-button routerLink="itemmnfgtime" routerLinkActive="active">Item Manufacturing Time</button>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
                <button mat-button routerLink="template" routerLinkActive="active">Templates</button>
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
    </mat-card>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```